# Variences and adding them from independent random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, standard-deviation

If I have 3 random varibles X, Y and Z and X=Y+Z then var(X)=var(Y)+var(Z), but Y=X-Z therefore var(Y)=var(X)+var(Z), it is clear that these two contridict, so what makes one of them right and the other wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second version is wrong because random variables do NOT obey normal algebra: Since $X = Y + Z$,  $X$ is perfectly correlated with both $Y$ and $Z$, hence the second formula, which treats $X$ as independent of the other two variables, is incorrect.